# Spectral theory - how to prove this lemma?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

in Anver Friedman, *Foundations of Modern Analysis* I found a lemma (6.7.3):

If A is a self-adjoint operator and $\{E_\lambda\}$ is a spectral family such that $A=\int_m^{M+\varepsilon} \lambda dE_\lambda$, then for every polynomial $p(\lambda)$ we have $$p(A)=\int_m^{M+\varepsilon} p(\lambda) dE_\lambda.$$ Proof goes like this:
$$\left\|\left(A-\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k E(\Delta_k)\right)^2\right\| \le \eta^2.$$

Then author says that "Using the relations $E(\Delta_k)E(\Delta_j) = 0$ if $k\neq j$ and $\|AS-A^2\| \le \|A\| \eta$ we find that  $$\left\|A^2-\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda^2_k E(\Delta_k)\right\| \le c\eta."$$

Maybe I'm too tired today, but why is the first relation true and how to use both to get the last inequality?

($E(\Delta_k) = E_{\lambda_k} - E_{\lambda_{k-1}}$ and $m = \lambda_0 < \lambda_1 < \ldots <\lambda_n = M+\varepsilon$ is the partition of $[m,M+\varepsilon]$ )

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot tell by the phrasing of your question which statement is confusing you.

Comment: @T.A.E. Sorry, my english is not perfect. Thanks for replying. I'm confused by $E(\Delta_k)E(\Delta_l)=0$. Also, I don't understand why the last inequality in the quoted part is true.

Comment: So you're not aware that the spectral measure satisfies $E(S)E(T)=E(S\cap T)$ for Borel subsets $S$ and $T$? In particular this holds for intervals $[a,b)$ and $[c,d)$ for which $[a,b)\cap[c,d)=\emptyset$. I suspect the $\Delta$ notation isn't clear, and it's not the best so far as I am concerned, because they really mean an interval.

Comment: @T.A.E., oops, I know that. The problem is that this book doesn't say anything about spectral measures, only spectral family is defined so I couldn't manage to connect those facts (I'm quite new to functional analysis). Now it's clear, thank You very much!

Comment: You're welcome.